# How to use tqdm to iterate over a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, tqdm

I would like to know how long it takes to process a certain list.

```
for a in tqdm(list1):
    if a in list2:
        #do something
```

but this doesnt work. If I use `for a in tqdm(range(list1))` i wont be able to retrieve the list values.

Do you know how do do it?

Answer (score 31):

```
import tqdm

for p in tqdm.tqdm([10,50]):
    print(p)
```

or

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for p in tqdm([10,50]):
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 7):

I had also this problem.
In my case I wrote:

```
import tqdm
```

instead

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

Answer (score 4):

I've written so many answers because I personally have used all these at different places in my mini-projects and projects. Some may be irrelevant according to question, but will be useful elsewhere.

```
list1 = list(range(100))

import tqdm
for x in tqdm.tqdm(list1):
        sleep(0.01)
```

Or

```
tlist1 = tqdm.tqdm(list1)
for x in tlist1:
        sleep(0.01)
```

Basically, you are passing the list to create a tqdm instance.

You can use another workaround as in [tqdm documentation](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm):

```
# DOESN't work well in terminal, but should be ok in Jupyter Notebook
with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(list1)) as t:
    for x in list1:
        sleep(0.01)
        t.update(1)
```

Using generators with manual update of trange object:

```
def literate(list1):
    t = trange(len(list1))
    for x in list1:
        t.update(1)
        yield x

for x in literate(list1):
    sleep(0.01)
```

With automatic update:

```
def li_iterate(li):
    l = iter(li)
    for _ in trange(len(li)):
        yield next(l)

for x in li_iterate(list1):
    sleep(0.01)
```

Apart from the question, if you are using pandas dataframe, you may want to use this sometime (in google-colaboratory):

```
# %% implies cell magic in google-colab
%%capture
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm as tq
tq().pandas()

def fn(x):
    for a in list2:
        print(x, a)

import pandas as pd
list1 = list(range(0, 9))
pd.DataFrame(data=list1).progress_apply(fn)
```

-*Himanshu*

Answer (score 0):

List is a list of elements in it, hence if you do `len(ls)`, it gives you number of elements in the list. `range` builtin function will iterate over the range, hence following for loop should work for `tqdm`

```
from tqdm import tqdm

ls = [i for i in range(0,20000000)]

for i in tqdm(range(len(ls))):
  ## code goes here ##
  pass
```